# How to access a S3 bucket accessible only through a EKS Pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-eks

We've got a S3 bucket we use to store files used by an application deployed on EKS, to access the bucket we have a secret web identity token.

The application maintenance guys sometime need to browse the S3 bucket to retrieve files, right now we have to start a pod with AWS CLI installed, then download the file to the pod and the use kubectl to copy the files to our local machine.

Is there a better way to do this without changing the bucket settings?

Comment: What would be the problem with attaching another policy to the bucket granting access to a IAM role?

Comment: @HenrikPingel I work in an enterprise environment and I do not control the infrastructure